# how to generate rank from mark php?

Tags: php, mysql

in my php project i have to upload students mark after exam and display the result by generating rank.When uploading mark if a student was absent mark field value is added as 'Absent'. So when generating rank list,
rank column of these student is denoted as  'Absent'.but when i use the following code mark denoted as 'Absent' has rank 1.

How to solve this? I am using datatables

```
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS student_id as sl,student_rollno, student_name, school_name as student_school,mark_mark,
 FIND_IN_SET( mark_mark, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( mark_mark
ORDER BY mark_mark DESC ) 
FROM mark )
)            
 as student_rank FROM student  JOIN class ON student_class=class_id JOIN school ON student_school=school_id  JOIN mark ON mark_student=student_id WHERE student_status=1        LIMIT 0, 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have to change the weight for the value 'Absent' in the order by clause of the group_concat: `GROUP_CONCAT( mark_mark
ORDER BY IF(mark_mark='Absent', '0', mark_mark) DESC )`

I used the string '0' because I assumed that the other marks are numbers. If this assumption is incorrect, then use any string or numerical value that has a lower order than your lowest mark grade.

Although, I would consider completely omitting the absent students from the list, but I'm not prvy to the business requirements.

Comment: i need 'Absent' students rank column as 'Absent'

Comment: Can you pls elaborate? I do not suggest to change the absent value.